# How to run an async websocket while running other code?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket

I have this code:

```
async def echo(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    websockets.serve(echo, 'localhost', 8765))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

But I want to run other code after the .run_forever() method, however that method makes the code hang. How do I keep executing code after this? Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html may help you.

Comment: @Yeheshuah None of those examples are using async or await..I'm not really sure how that's going to help me?